# Kendo DataSouce: Trying to Read from Remote Data Source

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to read from a remote data source using Kendo DataSource. "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

The browser successfully makes the AJAX call, and I'm unable to figure out what's wrong with Kendo internally. Their documentations are of no help.

Here's my code:

```
var accountsListDs = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://localhost:8085/cabinet/wicket/bookmarkable/com.finovera.web.services.AccountsService",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                op: "list" 
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/GtaHifJM

Comment: It might help if you showed the code that's actually using the data source. Is the data being returned valid JSON?

Comment: Can you show the JSON response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not with Kendo. Wicket doing some bizarre redirects to another URL, and the POST requests were getting converted to GET requests on the server side.